# Push to UIViewController from a UITabBarItem

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitabbaritem, pushviewcontroller

I encounter a problem using `UITabBarItem` and `UIButton` in my application. My button is inside a `UITabBarItem`. When I press it I want to be pushed to another controller to display a PDF.

Here is a piece of code that works in other cases :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   UIImage* imageButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pdf-button.png"];
   UIButton *buttonPDF = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   buttonPDF.frame = CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 100, 100, 200, 36);
   [buttonPDF setImage:imageButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   buttonPDF.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   buttonPDF.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
   [buttonPDF addTarget:self action:@selector(displayPDFParams:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:buttonPDF];
}

-(void)displayPDFParams:(UIButton *)sender {
    PDFProduitController *pdfController = [[PDFProduitController alloc] init];
    pdfController.pdf = documentParametres;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfController animated:YES];
}
```

`displayPDFParams` is called but  it not push me on my `pdfController`. I think it's because I'm not able to target the parent navigation controller of my application...
Anyone help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by define a property in my UIViewController (as UITabBarItem) like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *superNavController;
```

And set it in my UITabBarController :

```
self.myViewController.superNavController = self.navigationController;
```

Finally I modified my displayPDFParams method :

```
-(void)displayPDFParams:(UIButton *)sender {

   PDFProduitController *pdfController = [[PDFProduitController alloc] init];
   pdfController.pdf = self.documentParametres;

   [self.superNavController pushViewController:pdfController animated:YES];

}
```

Works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You need To initialize your root view controller with the navigation controller. Here is the code.

In your **AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeViewController.h"
@class HomeViewController;
@interface IDSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    UINavigationController *nav;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) HomeViewController *homeViewController;
@end
```

In your **AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "IDSAppDelegate.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  
    return YES;
}
```